# Problem with natbib installation on Windows 8

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, natbib, protext

I am using Texstudio following it's installation from `ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313.exe` ona Windows 8 machine.

For some reason, when I tried to install `natbib`, by following the instructions at

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/,

when I try to latex `natbib.ins` I get an error

```
Could not start Latex: Latex:
latex.ex -crc -interaction= nonstopmode "bibentry".tex.
```

followed by

```
Log file not found!
```

Why is this not working?

A separate yet related question: I also tried to install natbib from the MikTex package manager, but there I hit a problem in that for all the repositories I tried the plus sign for installation is always greyed out for `natbib` (and most packages for that matter). Why is that?

Comment: I doubt that TeXstudio really tries to start "latex.ex -crc". Also your command line tries to compile bibentry.tex and not natbib. So try to bit more precise regarding messages. You can install natbib with the package manager of miktex. There is not need to run some ins-files or do some manual installation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also with very low reputation you can edit your own questions and answers. no need for an additional comment.

Comment: @Speravir Feb 13 at 21:53done, thanks for the suggestion, now I have a user name more telling I guess!

Comment: @TiagoMarques: Yepp. :-)

Comment: As others comment, the message here seems completely unlikely. Please edit to make the question clearer.